# Sitecore: Send archiving emails

Tags: sitecore

I wanted to tryout sending reminder emails on archiving.
I have configured the webconfig email sending settings as follows:

```
<setting name="MailServer" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
  <!--  MAIL SERVER USER
        If the SMTP server requires login, enter the user name in this setting
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerUserName" value="xxxx@gmail.com"/>
  <!--  MAIL SERVER PASSWORD
        If the SMTP server requires login, enter the password in this setting
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerPassword" value="xxxxx"/>
  <!--  MAIL SERVER PORT
        If the SMTP server requires a custom port number, enter the value in this setting.
        The default value is: 25
  -->
  <setting name="MailServerPort" value="587"/>
```

I have selected an item and configured archiving options like archiving time, reminder email etc.
Item got archived, but it didn't send the reminder email.

How can I sort this email sending thing. I do not have Email Campaigner Module installed, do I need that to send emails?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the mailSettings node in your web.config?

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
        <smtp>
            <network host="127.0.0.1" />
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Comment: That isn't necessary with Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Email reminders and archiving are two separate functions.

To get the email reminders working, make sure you have a valid email address configured for the `EmailReminder.FromAddress` setting.

If that is already set, make sure that the `TaskDatabaseAgent` is scheduled to run (runs every 10 minutes by default) and check the logs for any issues when it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have ECM installed to send emails via a scheduled task.

The real way to sort out what the problem is would be to look in your logs.  Any scheduled task that is performed will put entries in the logs, including any errors that occur along the way.  I'd check there and see what is there regarding the items that are archived.  That's the best way of sorting out anything with Sitecore.

Answer (score 0):

Just ad the below node in web.config at the last but before :

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

It looks like as below:

[image]